# Ways of distributing passengers in ships

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, integer-partitions, set-partition, combinatorial-proofs

> I need help with the following combinatorial problem. There are $ K $ passengers and $ K $ ships. The passengers are denoted by $ U_1, U_2, \dots, U_K $. The objective is to find in how many ways the $ K $ persons can board the ships, with the following conditions:
>   1) The ships have a maximum capacity of $ N $ passengers
>   2) There exists at least one ship with exactly $ N $ persons
>   3) The rest of ships can have an arbitrary number of persons that is less or equal to $ N $ (thus, other ships can have $ 0, 1, 2, \dots, N $ passengers).
>   4) Not all the ships need to be used.

What matters here is the number of ways in which the persons can be grouped with the constraints above (which ships are used is not relevant). For instance, one case is $ N = K $, when all the persons board one single ship. The remaining $ K-1 $ ships are left empty. Another case is when $ N = 1 $. Thus, each person exclusively boards a different ship (all ships have exactly one person because all the passengers are required to board).

I have one example with $ K = 4 $, where I will denote the passengers by U1, U2, U3 and U4.

**Example 1:** When $ K = 4 $, $ N = 1 $,

Combination 1: [U1] [U2] [U3] [U4] (the order does not matter).

**Example 2:** When $ K = 4 $, $ N = 2 $, we have

Combination 1: [U1 U2] [U3] [U4] [empty]

Combination 2: [U1 U3] [U2] [U4] [empty]

Combination 3: [U1 U4] [U2] [U3] [empty]

Combination 4: [U2 U3] [U1] [U4] [empty]

Combination 5: [U2 U4] [U1] [U3] [empty]

Combination 6: [U3 U4] [U1] [U2] [empty]

Combination 7: [U1 U2] [U3 U4] [empty] [empty]

Combination 8: [U1 U3] [U2 U4] [empty] [empty]

Combination 9: [U1 U4] [U2 U3] [empty] [empty]

**Example 3:** When $ K = 4 $, $ N = 3 $, we have

Combination 1: [U1 U2 U3] [U4] [empty] [empty]

Combination 2: [U1 U2 U4] [U3] [empty] [empty]

Combination 3: [U1 U3 U4] [U2] [empty] [empty]

Combination 4: [U2 U3 U4] [U1] [empty] [empty]

**Example 4:** When $ K = 4 $, $ N = 4 $, the only way is to put all the passengers in the same ship. Thus, we have

Combination 1: [U1 U2 U3 U4] [empty] [empty] [empty]

**Update:** Based on Paulo's answer, thus far I have this. In some cases this work but in others do not...

$$ \sum_{\substack{0 < n_1\leq\ldots\leq n_k\leq N\\[2pt]n_1+\ldots+n_k=K}}
\frac{1}{(k-1)!} \frac{K!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_k!} $$

**Useful results:**
When $ K = 4 $, $ N = 1 $, the number of combinations is 1
When $ K = 4 $, $ N = 2 $, the number of combinations is 9
When $ K = 4 $, $ N = 3 $, the number of combinations is 4
When $ K = 4 $, $ N = 4 $, the number of combinations is 1

When $ K = 5 $, $ N = 1 $, the number of combinations is 1
When $ K = 5 $, $ N = 2 $, the number of combinations is 25
When $ K = 5 $, $ N = 3 $, the number of combinations is 20
When $ K = 5 $, $ N = 4 $, the number of combinations is 5
When $ K = 5 $, $ N = 5 $, the number of combinations is 1

Comment: You said "at least one ship with $N$ people while the rest of the ships have at most $N$ people". Then the one that has at least $N$ can have more? Because that's what I assumed but then you say that when $N=1$, the only solution is one person per ship. In that case, $\textit{all}$ ships must have at most $N$ people. Which one is it?

Comment: $N$ is the maximum number of persons that a ship can have. Furthermore, it is required that at least there exists one ship that has that maximum number of persons.

Comment: I have updated the problem description. Hopefully, it is more understandable now.

Comment: Im writting an answer, but I personally don't find the outcome very satisfactory.

Comment: If it helps, I have computed manually for $K=5$ and $N=2$. For this case I get 25 combinations. I tried to approach this by induction, but I had no success.

Answer (score 2):

One ship must have $N$ people, which is also the maximum number of people per ship (there are $K\choose N$ ways of doing this). After that, this problem reduces to distributing $K-N$ people by $K-1$ ships, where the maximum number of people per ship is $N$.

The number of ways of dividing $n$ people in one group of $n_1$ people, one group of $n_2$, one of $n_3,\ldots,$ and one of $n_k$ can be shown to be

$$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_k!}$$

And now you consider every possible way of choosing how many elements are in each group and you sum all of them, and multiply by the number of ways you can choose the $N$ people for the "fixed" ship:
$${K\choose N} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\sum_{\substack{0< n_1\leq\ldots\leq n_k\leq N\\[2pt]n_1+\ldots+n_k=K-N}}\frac{\left(K-N\right)!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_k!}\right)$$

which I believe to be the answer, but I don't know whether it can be simplified.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Can you please clarify for me the notation of the inner-most sum? May I understand that the number of nested sums is variable? Also, in that summation, it should be $ ...= K - N $, right? Regarding the ratio inside the sums, is it $(K-N)!$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Damn I'm really getting sleepy, thank you. I'll edit it

Comment: And yes, (i'm not sure if this was your question but) the amount of terms coming from the inner most sum definitely varies with $k$.

Comment: Hi Paulo, can you check my update? I am not sure if I have been able to completely understand your solution. I have used an example and the numbers do not match.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had forgotten all the different ways that you can choose which people go on the first ship, the one with precisely $N$ people. And it also doesn't make sense to allow for groups of $0$ people. Because that corresponds to having a smaller $k$. I've edited accordingly. And your calculations now yield $S_1=1$ and $S_2=S_3=0$ where there's a factor of $4$ multiplying the sum. Hence you get the right result :) I'm sorry and very well spotted!

Comment: In your previous solution the numbers were a bit closer to real values. I will improve the redaction of the problem.

Comment: What do you mean closer to real values?

Comment: Which cases don't work for the new formula?

Comment: With the new formula, it does not work for $ K = 4, N = 2 $. I will include a list of the actual numbers of combinations that I obtained by exhaustive group creation (on paper).

Comment: This formula seems to be considering the order as well $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_k!}$. For instance for, $ n = 4, n_1 = 2, n_2 = 2 $, I get $\frac{4!}{2!2!} = 6 $ instead of 3. These three combinations should be [U1-U2 and U3-U4], [U1-U3 and U2-U4], [U1-U4 and U2-U3].

Comment: Ah... maybe you have to factor out the case of having groups with the same number elements. I'm not quite sure how to do that though

Answer (score 2):

The numbers you give for $K = 5$ are correct.  You have enough numbers to [look up the relevant sequence in the OEIS (On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences): search for "1,25,20,5,1"](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C25%2C20%2C5%2C1) and you find [a unique sequence A080510](http://oeis.org/A080510).  The title of this sequence is "Triangle read by rows: T(n,k) gives the number of set partitions of {1,...,n} with maximum block length k.", which is exactly the problem you're asking for, where the parameter n equals your parameter K, and the parameter k equals your parameter N.

The entry gives you the number of partitions for any (K, N) with K up to 11.  You can also see from the entry that there is no simple formula from well-known functions to compute this number, though the text does give you a formula that is fast enough to compute even for large values of N.

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful. This will help me in adapting the formula above accordingly.

Comment: I understand that the mentioned sequence is counting the number of partitions with an arbitrary length up to a maximum length k. Thus, partitions with maximum length k-1 are also being counted. In my case, I require to count all the partitions that have exactly a maximum of length of k.